# Not able to click on the element passed through variable in xpath. Variable is of another class

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+eventname+"')])"))); 

        WebElement editeve = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+eventname+"')])"));
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'abc2016Feb11ab')]"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(editeve);
        actions.perform();
        editeve.click();
```

Comment: have you try to put     System.out.println(); and see if the varaible data is coming or not?

Comment: are you sure you locator is fine and able to locate the element .. if not then post there the HTML code of element with it's parent code

Comment: ya locator is able to locate the element but click action is unable to perform

Comment: yes i tried with syso and geturl, both worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your value is coming fine with syso then create a string. concatenate your all value of xpath first and then pass it to your element

```
String xpathOfEvent ="//a[contains(.,'"+eventname+"')])"; 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathOfEvent)));
```

I am assuming your locator is fine and able to locate the element

Hope it will help you :)